# TFS 2012 - binary files are not generated when using automatic build

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, automated-deploy

I am newbie to TFS. 
I am trying to automate process of build upon checking in the code in TFS.
I setup a Controller and an Agent. I created a new build definition and set a "build" and "drop" folder on c:.
I check in the code, expecting to see the generated dll files in "drop" folders. There's none, just "logs" folder. The "binaries" folder in "build" folder is also empty. Apparently the binaries are not being generated at all. How can I have MSBuild to generate the dll files?
They are generated when I compile the website locally on my development machine under "bin\" folder. The solution is comprised of two separate projects: "core" and "web" where "core" is referenced within "web".
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked through the build logs?

Comment: Yes. The log reports that the build was successful, but there's a warning though

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(610,5): warning : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Builds\1\xx\Build on Commits\Sources\xx\Web\Web.csproj]

Comment: Does it have anything to do with that warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the `Summary` showing of your build that ran? Or are there errors in your build? You can check the log of the build by opening the build in Visual Studio and then click `View Log`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I mentioned above, the build was successful, but there's just a warning. I posted the warning on the above comment.

Comment: Ok, go to your `Build definition` and edit it and follow these steps. Go to the `Process` tab, go to the line `Items to build` and select the `...` at the end of that line. There will open a new window with in the first tab your solutions or projects. On the second tab there is `Configurations`, click this one open. Add a new line with the Add button and then select as `Configuration` `Release` and `Platform` `Any CPU`. Now queue a new build. Hopefully it is solved with this.

Comment: I did that and some other changes too, and the problem is solved. I got all the dll and other assets in my "build" folder. Thanks Tim.

Comment: No problem. We are here to help and do not forget to mark the answer as a real answer.